# Pairs two different list into a single map

Tags: java, list, hashmap, iterator

I have two lists in Java:

```
List<String> ENODE = Arrays.asList(
        "ENB1", "ENB2", "ENB3", "ENB4", "ENB5");
List<String> CLOUD = Arrays.asList(
        "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4");
```

And I want to iterate the elements in both of the lists to produce a hash map that pairs all element in list 1 with all element in list 2 which result in something like below:

```
("ENB1","C1"), ("ENB1","C2"), ("ENB1","C3"),("ENB1","C4")
("ENB2","C1"), ("ENB2","C2"), ("ENB2","C3"),("ENB2","C4")
```

and so on.

Any idea on how I could do this?

Comment: Yea, you can do this really easily with a little bit of research and effort.

Comment: Wow, rawtypes and a flagrant disregard for Java naming conventions. Good work. Next step ... switch to Javascript. On another note - you know `Map` maps a **unique** key to a value right?

Comment: The keys of the map must be unique, otherwise it wouldn't be a map. Maybe you just want a list of pairs?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you've specified in your question with a `Map` since the keys need to be unique. You can, however, do it with a primitive `String[][]` array or a list of your own "pair" dto.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> enode = Arrays.asList("ENB1", "ENB2", "ENB3", "ENB4", "ENB5");
    List<String> cloud = Arrays.asList("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4");

    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String e : enode) {
        for (String c : cloud) {
            pairs.add(new Pair(e, c));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(pairs);
}

private static class Pair {

    final String key;

    final String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public Pair(String key, String value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder().append("(").append(this.key).append(",").append(this.value).append(")")
                .toString();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each key in a `Map` can only point to a single entry, so you can't have a `Map<String, String>`. But you can have a `Map<String, List<String>>` ("map from string to a list of strings"). This code will create a map whose keys come from the first list, and whose values are a list of all of the values from the second list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> eNode = Arrays.asList("ENB1", "ENB2", "ENB3", "ENB4",
            "ENB5");
    List<String> cloud = Arrays.asList("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4");

    Map<String, List<String>> grouped = groupListsIntoMap(eNode, cloud);
    System.out.println("Map:\n" + grouped);
}

public static Map<String, List<String>> groupListsIntoMap(List<String> keys,
        List<String> values) {
    int size = Math.min(keys.size(), values.size());
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int keyIndex = 0; keyIndex < keys.size(); ++keyIndex) {
        String key = keys.get(keyIndex);
        for (int valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < values.size(); ++valueIndex) {
            map.computeIfAbsent(key, r -> new ArrayList<>()).add(values.get(
                    valueIndex));
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Map:
{ENB1=[C1, C2, C3, C4],
ENB2=[C1, C2, C3, C4],
ENB3=[C1, C2, C3, C4],
ENB4=[C1, C2, C3, C4],
ENB5=[C1, C2, C3, C4]}
```

Note that you should always declare the parameter type of a Java collection such as `List` or `Map`. Here it seems that your keys and values are always `String` so we declare the lists as `List<String>` ("list of strings"). This enforces type safety and gives you a nice, clear compiler error if you try to add a non-string type to the list.

And if `ENODE` and `CLOUD` are mutable variables then you should name them in lowercase, with a name such as 'eNode' or 'enode'. This is known as a Java naming convention, and it makes it easier to read and review your code. If, on the other hand, these are `static final` class fields then it is correct to give them an ALL_UPPERCASE_SEPARATED_BY_UNDERSCORES name, to show that they should be treated as constants (immutable, unmodifiable).