# How to join two different lists into a single Pair without nested loops and to avoid OutOfMemory Error?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, pairing

Given: 2 Lists of String. Required: List<Pair<String, String>> countryStatus.

Following the answer from @geco17 with two for loops I am getting into OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space due to the amount of data.

Is there any other way to do so and avoid OutOfMemory Error?

[Pairs two different list into a single map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49209216/pairs-two-different-list-into-a-single-map)

```
        for (String country : countrylist) {
            for (String status : statusList) {
                nodesCountryStatus.add(new Pair(country, status));
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE**: As a possible way to avoid this problem but to solve the task I had not straightforward I did the following - concatinating two lists by each element in sequence [Zipping streams using JDK8 with lambda (java.util.stream.Streams.zip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17640754/zipping-streams-using-jdk8-with-lambda-java-util-stream-streams-zip). I was to have the output in csv thus commas appropriate:

`if (countries.size() == statuses.size()) { countryStatusAsExtracted = Streams.zip(countries.stream(), statuses.stream(), (a, b) -> (a + "," + b)) .collect(Collectors.toList());}`

Comment: Well, the result of creating every single pair of 2 lists with length N and M will result in N*M `Pair` objects. This will be problematic for big numbers of N an M, what numbers are we talking about here? You can assign more maximum memory to your JVM, but after all it's limited by your machine's hardware.

Comment: @f1sh, 7200 for N and 7200 for M

Answer (score 0):

Since you already know how long your resulting list will be, you can initialize the `ArrayList` with the size. It should be `country.size() * statusList.size`. That way you avoid reallocating the list constantly.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately, it does not help